# How to update avatar/photo of a model directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins

This is rails 3.0.x. I was just wondering how to update an attribute of a model's photo/avatar directly without prompting the user to upload from his/her system?

I am using [Paperclip](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html) to attach a photo to a model; It has the extension so that a user can use a URL to upload a photo. This works.

Now, I was looking at [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/), and it returns an image of the canvas so user's can download them.

I was wondering how to use the URL that Canvas2Image returns so I can update the current model's photo directly?

For now, I have this form that prompts the user to update the current model's avatar/photo:

```
<% form_for(@prototype,
            :url=>{:controller=>"prototypes",
            :action=>"update"}, 
            :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

    <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br><br>
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %><br><br>
    <%= submit_tag   "Save Prototype" %>

<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link to Canvas2Image above it looks to me like you are trying to handle Base64-encoded images (like `data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wB`).

Paperclip expects a `Tempfile` object, which is created behind the scenes for you when you upload an image.  It is possible to fake a `Tempfile` by using a `StringIO` object and adding `content_type` and `original_filename` instance methods.

I posted a gist with the code I used to accomplish this in one of my projects.  https://gist.github.com/1012107.

For you to do something similar you'd need to remove the beginning portion of the Canvas2Image URIs `data:image/octet-stream;base64,` and use the remaining Base64 code as the image_data.  You'd need a way to provide or work around the content-type and filename.

If you just want to use normal URLs like `http://example.com/image.jpg` then you have several available options.

You could simply save the URL and use it as an image source on your pages.  I know this isn't always an option, and you have no control over the availability of the image.

Otherwise, there are several utilities such as net/http and curl that you could use to download the image.  If you think you want to go this route then you might also consider downloading the images using delayed jobs or a similar background process.  That way your UI doesn't hang if the image download is slow.

Comment: This is relevant to my question. I was wondering what you meant with content-type and filename? Content type as in, PNG, JPG, etc? File name as in have the code provide one instead of the image data as the name? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, content-type as in PNG, JPG, etc.

Comment: I think auto-generating the filename in your case would be a good idea.

Comment: In your gist, does it assume all images coming through are Base64-encoded?

Comment: No, regular file uploads also work.  In fact the application I pulled the example from uses both methods.  The normal file upload is used for the Web UI, and the Base64 method is used for a JSON API, so that users can upload photos from an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the gravatar using users' email address you can use the following code snippet.

In a helper:

```
def avatar_url(user)    
 gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
 return "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"         
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(avatar_url(user)), user_path(user))%>
```

That's it! You need not to ask user to upload your photo in your system. It will show the photo of his gravatar account. Please let me know whether it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Fuad! This is wonderful for my user's profile. Right now though, its not what I'm looking for. My users have alot(has_many relationship) of prototypes and these prototypes have an image attached to them! Just wondering how I can let the users edit these images through a canvas and save it directly to the server.(My ultimate goal)

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://trevorturk.com/2008/12/11/easy-upload-via-url-with-paperclip/) might be what you're looking for

However, if you haven't done much work with paperclip yet, I would recommend you to swap to CarrierWave.
The same thing is done with two lines of code:

```
@prototype.image_remote_url = canvas2image_url #you should change this
@prototype.save
```

Comment: Hey bassneck! Thanks for answering. I already impelemented this feature with Paperclip(I mentioned "a user can use a URL to upload a photo"). Still, it asks the user to provide the URL for the image. I was asking how to do it using an image provided by Canvas2Image(look at my link for the demo). Where the user draws on a canvas, converts it to an image and presses a button to overwrite the current image of the prototype!